# How to terminate Appium session when stopping program in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python-appium

I'm using behave with Appium in a PyCharm debugger to debug an app. I am calling behave from Python using this code:

```
rc = run_behave(config=myconfig, runner_class=MyBehaveRunner)
```

How can I intercept the debugger's [STOP] button/signal and call `context.driver.quit()` on the driver so that the Appium server terminates the current session id instead of eventually timing out? `context.driver` (for calling `context.driver.quit()` ) only seems to be accessible within a behave step, so I don't know how to set up a signal handler to do this.